# Wi-fi was wrong one

Tags: time-machine

How do you change wi-Fi on time capsule. It automatically set  guest  instead of secured  setting .  Tried soft rest still  no place to change wi-fi

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your question is a bit confusing.  What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is set up in the Airport Utility. If you have a Mac, you find it under Applications, Utilities. If you have an iPhone or iPad only, you download it from the App Store.

If that doesn't help, you will have to tell us what you are trying to do on which devices. Can't see your network on any device? Can see it but not connect? What was changed at around the time it stopped working? What's connected to the Time Capsule (Router, cables, other Airports...). Does your main Router work normally? And so on.